# PCI Pass-through in MacOS

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, macintosh

I'm trying to attach my PCI devices to my Debian installation, I'm on a Mac OS host I know there is official support for PCI Passthrough in VirtualBox on Linux hosts, but I don't know if there is support for PCI Passthrough in MacOS, I tried Qemu and I don't know how to attach PCI devices to my VM, Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCI passthrough has been dropped ([commit here](https://github.com/mdaniel/virtualbox-org-svn-vbox-trunk/commit/5178e479b2ac1e33454f203854de9fe8f85a9196)) for now from VirtualBox altogether, [it seems](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17730#comment:7). It was also only available for Linux hosts.

**From [VirtualBox 6.1 changelog](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog):**

> Linux host: Drop PCI passthrough, the current code is too incomplete (cannot handle PCIe devices at all), i.e. not useful enough

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, according to [VirtualBox documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough) the PCI passthrough functionality is **only** applicable when using Linux as the host OS. You would also need to have the optional VirtualBox Extension Pack installed.